# Algolia Infiniti scroll is not working in React Native Hooks

Tags: react-native, algolia, react-instantsearch

I need to implement the Algolia search filter in a react native .All Filters, sorts are working, but infinite scroll is not working .I am using FlatList to load the list .
Below is the code used

```
import {
  InstantSearch,
  connectInfiniteHits,
} from 'react-instantsearch-native';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/reactnative';


  <InstantSearch
    searchState={{refinementListFilter }}
    searchClient={searchClient}
    indexName={sortValueState}
  >
    <VirtualWidgets />
    <InfiniteHits />

  </InstantSearch>

 const InfiniteHits = connectInfiniteHits(({ hits, hitsPerPage, hasMore, refineNext }) => {
const onEndReached = () => {
  if (!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
    if (hasMore) {
      try {
       refineNext();
       setonEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum(true);

      } catch (error) {
        console.log('onEndReached22', error);
      }
    }
  }
};

return (
  <FlatList
    data={hits} //hits
    ref={flatListRef}
    renderItem={VehicleListItem}
    style={{
      paddingVertical: hpx(20),
    }}
    contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
    onEndReached={() => onEndReached()}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
      setonEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum(false);
    }}
   
  
  />
);
```

});

Can anyone help